# Load/unload new views in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently testing this environment and would like to ask about the best strategy loading/unloading for a multiview application.

The app i am playing around with should have the following:

Main: a normal view with 5 x buttons (Play, Leaderboard, Properties, Instructions and an "i" button for about)

The Properties is a tableView where each cell opens up a new tableView with the actual properties.

What is the best strategy from a flexibility and memory point of view to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the extra views in their own nib-files. Load them in when needed using `+[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"nibFileName" owner:self]`. Replace `self` with whatever object that you want the nib's "File's Owner" to point to. (Usually it would be `self`, though, since it would be the view's *controller* whose job it was to create the nib; and the controller is also typically what you want as your File's Owner.)

**Disclaimer**: I'm basing this on my knowledge of Cocoa on the desktop, but I'm pretty sure nib-files work the same on the iPhone.